# OWL existential restrictions and Necessary conditions

Tags: owl, protege, restriction

I'm creating an ontology using protege05 and I have a question in regard to property restrictions. What I've understood from the protege tutorial is that when we assign a property to a class using restrictions, it means that this property is necessary for defining that class.

for example, suppose i have classes "Orthodox Church" and "Sanctuary" and a property "hasPart and i want to say that "an Orthodox Church hasPart Sanctuary".

If I use existential restriction apparently it will mean that "having Sanctuary" is necessary for a building to be an  Orthodox Church or if a building is an Orthodox Church it must ALWAYS have a Sanctuary.(but it's not always correct).
so my question is that how should insert this property without it being necessary for defining my class? in other words, how can i say that this property is SOMETIMES correct for my class but not ALWAYS?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You want to use Orthodox Church as domain for your property - so, when used, you will infer the building is a church. It won't stop you from creating churches without sanctuaries.

Without changing the domain, you could create a class with 'some hasPart Sanctuary' as a subclass of 'Orthodox Church' - a sufficient but not necessary condition.

Comment: If I do that then i won't be able to assign "hasPart" property to my other classes. for instance, the class "Temple".

Comment: In that case what we're saying is that a class with 'some hasPart Sanctuary' is a subclass of 'Orthodox Church' - a sufficient but not necessary condition.